# Извлечение данные из JSON в Python

Tags: python, api, sqlite3, qiwi

Я работаю с qiwi api на python 3.9. Мне нужно извлечь определенные данные из json'а и записать их в бд.

Есть следующий код:

```
token = 'api token'
wallet = 'wallet number'

def payment_history():
    s = requests.Session()
    s.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token  
    parameters = {'rows': 10} # последние 10 платежей
    h = s.get('https://edge.qiwi.com/payment-history/v2/persons/' + wallet + '/payments', params = parameters)
    return h.json()
```

Ответом мне приходит json, где в data идут последние 10 платежей. Вот кусок из json'а:

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "txnId":12345678901,
            "personId":79161112233,
            "date":"2021-07-30T14:29:33+03:00",
            "errorCode":0,
            "error":"None",
            "status":"SUCCESS",
            "type":"IN",
            "statusText":"Success",
            "trmTxnId":"1122334455667",
            "account":"",
            "sum":{
                "amount":12,
                "currency":643
            },
            "comment":"None",
            "currencyRate":1,
        },
        {
            "txnId":12345678902,
            "personId":79161112233,
            "date":"2021-07-30T14:29:11+03:00",
            "errorCode":0,
            "error":"None",
            "status":"SUCCESS",
            "type":"IN",
            "statusText":"Success",
            "trmTxnId":"11223344556",
            "account":"",
            "sum":{
                "amount":8,
                "currency":643
            },
            "comment":"комментарий к платежу",
            "currencyRate":1,
        }
    ],
    "nextTxnId":"None",
    "nextTxnDate":"None"
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно извлечь из этого json'а значения `txnId`, `sum.amount` и `comment`? Буду благодарен любой помощи

Comment: А что попробовали *вы*? Этот сайт не предназначен для просьб написать код за вас. Расскажите, что вы попробовали, что не получилось, что непонятно в документации.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko я не просил писать готовый код. В вопросе еще была затронута субд, но с этим уже разобрался. Я прошу лишь подсказать, как извлекать определнные значения из json'а.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавлю комментарии по нескольким строкам json-а, дальше, надеюсь, будет понятнее:

```
{
```

Начало `json`-а, все элементы, которые лежат на следующем уровне можно получить, обращаясь как к словарю (фигурная скобка - это словарь в питоне): `json[key]`

```
    "data":[
```

Соответственно, то, что лежит в `data` получаем так `json['data']`.
Но дальше мы видим квадратную скобку, это значит в элементе json-а `data` лежит список, а не просто значение.

```
        {
```

А тут мы видим, что первым же элементом списка, т.е. `json['data'][0]`, начался ещё один словарь.

```
            "txnId":12345678901,
```

Берём ту конструкцию, которая у нас получалась выше и обращаемся к ней как к словарю за элементом `txnId`: `json['data'][0]['txnId']`

```
            ...
            "sum":{
                "amount":12,
            ...
```

А тут тоже самое, что и выше, только элемент словаря другой, а в нём опять ещё один словарь (фигурная скобка): `json['data'][0]['sum']['amount']`.

Если сами не можете догадаться или сомневаетесь, что же там дальше, ничто не мешает вам на любом этапе остановиться, напечатать элемент до которого вы добрались, и посмотреть - а что же там дальше в нём лежит, например:

```
print(json['data'][0]['sum'])
```

Это я добрался вручную в самый первый элемент списка в `'data'`. Чтобы добраться до остальных элементов этого списка, их нужно перебрать циклом `for`, доступ их нижележащим элементам будет точно такой же, как мы разобрались выше для первого (с индексом `0`) элемента:

```
for item in json['data']:
   print(item['sum']['amount']
```

Пользуясь этой методикой вы легко можете добраться до любого элемента `json`:

- к элементам в фигурных скобках обращаемся как к значениям словаря (по ключу)
- к элементам в квадратных скобках обращаемся как к элементам списка (по индексу, обычно мы перебираем их через `for`)
- через запятую идут элементы, лежащие на одном уровне
- после двоеточия идёт следующий уровень, где может лежать либо одно значение, либо словарь, либо список

Comment: Очень полезно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

В json у вас словарь, состоящий из списка словарей, где каждый словарь это платеж. Вам нужно работать с этим как с соответствующими типами питона

Пример:

```
history = payment_history()
for payment in history['data']:
    print(payment['txnId'], payment['personId'], payment['date'], payment['sum']['amount'])
```

Извлечете нужные данные из `payment` и добавите `INSERT`'ом в таблицу базы данных

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @kelent, пожалуйста :)